# Is there an option to remove unused references on save in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, automated-refactoring

Is there an option to remove and sort usings automatically on save for the current document? This used to be provided by the [Power Commands for Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio). Is this available somewhere in the Visual Studio 2022 options? Or is provided by some other extension?

I tried searching in the Tools>Options. And also searched the web for a while, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done with the Code Cleanup feature.  Starting in 17.1 Preview 2, this can be triggered on save.  See the announcement at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bringing-code-cleanup-on-save-to-visual-studio-2022-17-1-preview-2/

On versions prior to that, there is an extension that works with either VS2019 or VS2022 called [Code Cleanup On Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CodeCleanupOnSave)

Comment: But it does not remove unused properties

Comment: @herve It does not by default, but it can be configured to remove unused references.